# How to increase the text field label size (width) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There is any way to increase the text field label width in flutter, to avoid the ellipses (...)?

The label is always smaller than the text field area.

All I could think to improve this, was decrease the "start" and "end" of content padding, but the effect is minimal.

```
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "em Dólares",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber[600],
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        fillColor: Colors.black12,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, start: 5.0, end: 5.0),  //<-- weak solution
                        prefixText: "US\$"),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber[600], fontSize: 20.0),
                  )
```

Ps: I hide in the code above some unecessary properties from the text field, as controller, inputFormatters, keyboardType.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you could modify your `floatingLabelStyle` and `floatingLabelAlignment`(as opposed to the `labelStyle`):

```
        TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'I am a very long text string yes I am',
              prefixText: "US\$",
              floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image: Floating label Screenshot]
[image: Normal label Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To change(reduce/increase) the font size of a label you can use `fontSize:` attribute in `TextStyle()`. Just add font size to label.

Comment: Yes, as I already use. The question is not about font size, but about the field label size. Thank you.

Comment: you can use `TextField ` inside a container and set height and width to the container

Answer (score 0):

Shrink the font size of the label text using the `fontSize` property in `labelStyle`. Flutter will display the ellipses if the text for the label goes over about half the size of the text field (I cannot find this in the documentation, but have dealt with this issue myself).

```
  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "em Dólares",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber[600],
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 10),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        fillColor: Colors.black12,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, start: 5.0, end: 5.0),  //<-- weak solution
                        prefixText: "US\$"),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber[600], fontSize: 20.0),
                  )
```